# Add/Merge element from from one Object to another Object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I have the following code in my async function

```
async function test () {
    try {
        const aucs = await auctions.find({owner: 'owner', place: 'place'}).limit(15);
        const item = await Promise.all(aucs.map(async aucs => {
            const map = await items.find({id: aucs.item});
            return map[0]
        }));
        --->we are here [1]
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

test();
```

and the point `[1]` I have two arrays avaliable which contain another objects (both are responces from Mongo) here they are:

```
aucs = [ { _id: 5c00faa4936359120ceb3632,
    auc: 177215422,
    item: 130251,
    price: 26000000,
    lastModified: 1543567955000,
    date: 2018-11-30T08:53:56.290Z,
    __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5c00faa4936359120ceb363f,
    auc: 177215440,
    item: 130251,
    price: 26000000,
    lastModified: 1543567955000,
    date: 2018-11-30T08:53:56.290Z,
    __v: 0 },... ]
```

and

```
item = [ { _id: 5bcd8a6134cdd1223cd3239b,
    id: 130251,
    name: 'TEST_NAME_1',
    __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5bcd8a6134cdd1223cd3239b,
    id: 130252,
    name: 'TEST_NAME_2',
    __v: 0 },...]
```

And I'd like to add to `aucs[i]`every element in aucs,  `item[i].name` (`name: 'TEST_NAME_1'`)
Like:

```
combined = [ { _id: 5c00faa4936359120ceb3632,
        auc: 177215422,
        item: 130251,
        name: 'TEST_NAME_1',
        price: 26000000,
        lastModified: 1543567955000,
        date: 2018-11-30T08:53:56.290Z,
        __v: 0 },...]
```

I'm trying to use `for` loop with `auc[i].name = item[i].name` or using `aucs.push()` but for some unknown reason it wasn't worked for me.
I receive error for `.push is not a function` and for loop didn't add anything. So maybe someone have any idea?

> Note: 1

actually solve one problem with item, mongo returns me array inside array like `[ [ { ...} ] ]` so I should using return map[0] to fix it.

> Note: 2

both of aucs and item are object according to typeof and have .length option (they are both the same length and should be all the time. So they are not promises

> Note: 3

`let merged = {...aucs, ...item};` returns me

```
{ '0': { _id: 5bcd8a6134cdd1223cd3239b,
     id: 130251,
     name: 'JewelCraft',
     icon: 'inv_jewelcrafting_70_jeweltoy',
     stackable: 1,
     isAuctionable: true,
     __v: 0 }...
```

but not what I need to

Comment: Instead of adding information in comments, I would suggest to update the question itself (with "edit").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be more superior and faster if you use some aggregation trick here

```
auctions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "owner": "owner", "place": "place" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "items",
    "let": { "item": "$item" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$id", "$$item"] }}}
    ],
   "as": "item"
  }},
  { "$limit": 15 }
])
```

Comment: Will it work on two collections? I have both `itmes` and `auctions` in use. And as i see, here is only `auctions` collection.

Comment: Yes it will work. See the `from` part in `$lookup` aggregation. You can see `items` there. It will bring all the `items` matched with the `id`

Comment: You should read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the aim is to create a new collection of `aucs` like the ones found, each updated to include an item name from the `item` collection where the item has a matching id.

```js
let aucs = [ { _id: "5c00faa4936359120ceb3632",
    auc: 177215422,
    item: 130251,
    price: 26000000,
    lastModified: 1543567955000,
    date: "2018-11-30T08:53:56.290Z",
    __v: 0 },
    { _id: "5c00faa4936359120ceb363f",
    auc: 177215440,
    item: 130251,
    price: 26000000,
    lastModified: 1543567955000,
    date: "2018-11-30T08:53:56.290Z",
    __v: 0 } ];
 
item = [ { _id: "5bcd8a6134cdd1223cd3239b",
    id: 130251,
    name: 'TEST_NAME_1',
    __v: 0 },
    { _id: "5bcd8a6134cdd1223cd3239b",
    id: 130252,
    name: 'TEST_NAME_2',
    __v: 0 }];
    
// create a new collection of aucs modified to include the names of matching items
let combined = [];
aucs.forEach(auc => {
    let combinedAuc = Object.assign({}, auc);
    combined.push(combinedAuc);
    let matchingItem = item.find(i => auc.item === i.id);
    if (matchingItem) combinedAuc.name = matchingItem.name
});

console.log(combined)
```

Comment: it is possible to do w/o ```underscore```? Seems that it is working fine, but I'm trying to do it w/o addition modules. So does ```_.method``` represent ```array.prototype```?

Comment: edited to show without underscore.  that's a useful library for other stuff, too.